# Mimic Button Click with POST Request JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that runs on YouTube. I want to be able to trigger the subscribe button click from javascript using a POST request.

I have been able to extract the POST request URL when a user clicks the Subscribe button (using the chrome network screen)

I have then used this URL in my own POST request and I get a 400 error and a response saying "Precondition check failed"

Now when I check the difference between my POST request and the POST request from the user interface(Clicking Subscribe button). I found that my request is specifying that it is an XMLHttpRequest. Whereas the user interface version has a lot of Tokens and auth elements to it.

[image: Left is my POST Request Failing. Right is the POST Request when the user clicks the subscribe button]

Is it possible to actually mimic the POST request of a subscribe click? I am not looking for a workaround, I would just like to know if it is possible and how it can be done.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible. You need to create a hidden `<form>` and fill it with a bunch of hidden `<input>`s with all the parameters you need. Then programmatically `.submit()` it.

Comment: Interesting, so in doing this I will achieve a post request similar to the one thats on the right? Hardest thing might be getting all the parameters needed to pass into the form

Comment: Your comment got me thinking. Since your extension runs on the YouTube page, you probably don't need to _duplicate_ the subscribe button. Rather, you should be able to [programmatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) `.click()` the native subscribe button to achieve the same effect.

Comment: You are completely right but my problem is more complicated than that. Using the subscribe button as an example seemed like the best way to describe a complicated problem.

What I actually want to do is make a comment using the chrome extension. If I am able to trigger the a subscribe post from JS I can repurpose this code for making a comment. The issue with comments is that they use lazy load and therefore are not in the document element, so I can't use .click() on something that hasn't loaded in the DOM yet. If I can bypass all of YouTubes Checks and make a comment this would be good